What is this component on my msi computer motherboard?
I hope you are having a good day, I recently bought a broken msi meg z790 godlike and there are a few components that are burnt that needs replacing. I was wondering what this component is an smd thats shown on picture 1-2 (~3.5mm long and 3mm wide) that has the + symbol along with the code n8 eU. From what i've looked up it seems to be a type of diode? But im not sure and I can't find the specific component online. There is also this capacitor that is shown in picture 3-4 (~2.2mm long & ~1mm wide), which looks like an smd resistor or capacitor that is an orange or greenish kind of color (solid). This component was near the cpu socket and I cant find anything on this one. I know its in really bad condition but I am willing to try and fix these problems.
Thank you so much for your time





Inline images, don't make us go to another site to see them.

Please refer to the component identification guidelines for asking questions about identifying parts.

oh ok ill add them now

sorry I am new. I fixed the post so it fits the guidelines and I included the approximate dimensions for both components

All of the components circled here are capacitors. The black one in the first two images is a tantalum capacitor, and its value can probably be decoded by scanning various manufacturers' datasheets until one matches. The unmarked ones in the other images are ceramic capacitors, and you can't determine their value without desoldering and measuring them.

Thank you so much!

I will add, also, that the damage to the board looks likely too severe to practically repair. The missing tantalum capacitors look like they were removed partially with a chisel, and who knows what inner layers got destroyed in that?

yeah, I did power it on and it seems to power on just fine. Not sure about the cpu power or anything else but hopefully I might be able to restore it.
